# Allow user to read files and folders - Windows Server 2012

Tags: iis, permissions, windows-server-2012, windows, file-permissions

Our server appears to have some weird permissions issues. Random files and folders within our web server directory do not have the permissions to allow our `webuser` to read files.

I am not sure why this is, but it needs fixing. Is there a way to give `webuser`, read permissions across the whole disk / OS? Without affecting the other permissions?

I know how to do this for a particular file or folder, but this is obviously tedious to change each time. I would like the user to be able to read all files that currently exist, and that will be created in the future.

Comment: Are these random files/folders being uploaded via FTP or through the web application?

Comment: It varies, some are deployed through FTP, others are uploaded from PHP. But I guess the ones uploaded from PHP would be sent to the temp folder at first, which previously didn't have the right permissions.

Comment: Make sure `webuser` has rights to the parent folder and set that folder to recursively set permissions and inherit permissions beneath it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of folders/files with explicit/un-inherited permissions on the OS partition.  Even granting it at the root of C won't filter to everything.

My advice would be to set it on the web server directory properly and check that folders/files within that directory are set if they need uninherited permissions.  If the whole folder structure inherits permissions from it's own root then granting 'webuser' READ access to that directory will propogate down to any new files/folders that are created in the future as long as they aren't created with explicit un-inherited rights.

Also make sure the `webuser` is in the right Local group on the server, and that the permissions are correct within IIS on the website itself if necessary.